# Passing CLGeocoder city name with delegate protocol

Tags: objective-c, class, clgeocoder

I´m trying to pass the placemark locality from CLGeocoder to another class UILabel named cityLabel. The class with CLGeocoder named WXManager and the mainViewController named WXController. I have tried every way around to make it work, but I simply can´t get the city name passed to the cityLabel.

WXManager.h

```
@class WXManager;
@protocol WXManagerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)WXManagerDidGeocodeCityName:(NSString *)cityName;

@end

@interface WXManager : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations;
@end
```

WXManager.m

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
if (self.isFirstUpdate) {
    self.isFirstUpdate = NO;
    return;
}

CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];

if (location.horizontalAccuracy > 0) {
    self.currentLocation = location;
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];}


CLGeocoder *fgeo = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

// Reverse Geocode a CLLocation to a CLPlacemark
[fgeo reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error){

               if(!error){

                   for(CLPlacemark *placemark in placemarks){
                       self.cityName = [placemark locality];
                       [self.customDelegate WXManagerDidGeocodeCityName:self.cityName];
                       NSLog(@"city is %@",cityName); }

               } else {
                   NSLog(@"There was a reverse geocoding error\n%@",
                         [error localizedDescription]);
               }
           }
 ];
 }
```

WXController.h

```
@interface WXController : UIViewController
<WXManagerDelegate> 

- (void)WXManagerDidGeocodeCityName:(NSString *)cityName;

@end
```

And at last in WXController.m where the problem seems to be, my method WXManagerDidGeocodeCityName wont get called. And I don´t know what´s wrong. Does anyone know how to make this method get called?

```
WXManager *cityName = [[WXManager alloc] init];
cityName.customDelegate = self;

#pragma mark - Custom Delegate Method

- (void)WXManagerDidGeocodeCityName:(NSString *)cityName
{

[self.cityLabel setText:cityName];
NSLog(@"cityName is %@", cityName);
NSLog(@"DidGetCalled");
}
```

The log doesnt get called so there´s got to be something missing somewhere.

Comment: how is customDelegate defined

Comment: oh missed that,
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <WXManagerDelegate> customDelegate;

Comment: are you holding on to city name? else it is not retained and it goes away

Comment: how would I go about that?

Comment: keep it in a instance variable, maybe ..

Comment: I´m not sure what to put in that instance variable or where to put it

Comment: hold the WXManager *clientName

Comment: in the class that also implements the delegate protocol

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**WXManager.h**

```
@class WXManager;
@protocol WXManagerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)WXManagerDidGeocodeCityName:(NSString *)cityName;

@end

@interface WXManager : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
id <WXManagerDelegate> customDelegate;
}

@property (retain)id customDelegate;

@end
```

**WXController.h**

```
@interface WXController : UIViewController <WXManagerDelegate> 

//- (void)WXManagerDidGeocodeCityName:(NSString *)cityName;

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

in WXManager.m you need initialize CLLocationManager:

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

self.locationManager.delegate = self;
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

and everything will work out fine

Comment: I don´t think it is that, because that part works ok. The NSLog from placemark locality shows the correct city.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that `cityName` is `weak`, or has a custom setter/getter that clears/ignores the correct value.

**Edit for clarification:**

I was talking about your `cityName` here:

```
WXManager *cityName = [[WXManager alloc] init];
cityName.customDelegate = self;
```

I was assuming it would be assigned some property `self.cityName` later on.
If you don't, your `self.customDelegate` will become `nil` by the time the completion handler runs.

Comment: it´s set to strong, nonatomic

Comment: I updated my answer to clarify which `cityName` I was talking about.

Comment: hmm, I still don´t get it. The completionhandler runs, is supposed to send the cityName to the WXController where I set the cityName-delegate. Where would you suggest putting it?

Answer (score 1):

The method is not called? Or variable cityName equal nil?

If first - look for your delegate may be it equal nil.
If second - CLGeocoder work not correct.

Generally stroll debugger. Look at the variables. Quickly understand everything.

Comment: CLGeocoder works, it returns a city name. The method WXManagerDidGeocodeCityName: does not get called at all, therefore it doesnt return anything.

Comment: Pierre, look for your customDelegate. May be it equal nil. 
You know how to use the debugger? Put a breakpoint at the point where the method is called the delegate. Print customDelegate. 
Here it is: 
    po self.customDelegate

Answer (score 0):

in WXManager.m you need initialize CLLocationManager:

> self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
>   self.locationManager.delegate = self; [self.locationManager
>   startUpdatingLocation];

and everything will work out fine